# XML Serialization produces random strings at the end? C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

When seralizing a class and saving to a file, sometimes an error occurs where the serialized output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Template xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Route>Some Route</Route>
    <TradePack>Something Here</TradePack>
    <Transport />
</Template>te> ------> Notice this extra string?
```

The class I'm serializing looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Template
{
    public string Route = string.Empty;
    public string TradePack = string.Empty;
    public string Transport = string.Empty;

    public Template()
    {

    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Here's my serializer class:

```
    public static bool Save(object obj, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                writer.Serialize(stream, obj);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch { }
        return false;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar problem once, on my end it was the fault that the file never got cleaned completely. It was always a piece left. Maybe delete the file before you write to it.

Comment: Ah makes sense, thank you! :)

Comment: So, as I expected. It is almost never random ;).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The additional output is likely a leftover from a previous version of the output file (having the same name).

You can solve the problem by changing the [`FileMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx) from `OpenOrCreate`to `Create` only. That way the output file is truncated if it already exists.

An even simpler method would be to use `File.Create(path)`:

```
XmlSerializer writer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
using (var stream = File.Create(path))
{
    writer.Serialize(stream, obj);
}
```

As an aside: It is usually preferable to just let exceptions bubble up the call stack until you can do something meaningful with them. Just silently swallowing the exception and instead returning a status flag which might never be checked hides the actual problem, might lead to further issues later on and makes a problem analysis unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: And let's mention the `File.Create(path)` shortcut.

Comment: I've changed FileMode to Truncate and beforehand create the file if it doesn't yet exist.

Comment: @HenkHolterman This really isn't a lot of work, besides I don't like using external libs when not necessary.

Comment: @J.Doe: `File.Create` isn't an external library, it's part of .NET.

Comment: I didn't know what you had in mind, but I've used File.Create then.